# Get data from link with jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following link;

www.example.com/profile.php?u=aaron

I will like to get the `u=` using ajax to echo the details saved with the name `aaron` in my database. But when ever I try to achieve this with my ajax code, I end up getting a blank page as my result.

**MY AJAX CODE;**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({    
        type: "GET",
        url: "fetch.php",             
        data: "u=":usr,   
        success: function(d) {                    
             $("#detail").html(d); 
        }
    });
});
```

**fetch.php;**

```
<?php  
    // connect to db
    include 'db.php';

    if (isset($_GET['usr'])) {
        $user_query = "SELECT details FROM users_det WHERE name = ?";
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_var, $user_query)) {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_GET['usr']);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $details);
            while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
                // fetch results
            }

            // close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }

        // echo user details
        echo $details;
    }
?>
```

**MY HTML CODE;**

```
<div id="detail"></div>
```

**AND THE FOLLOWING PHP CODE IN MY HTML CODE;**

```
  <?php 
    $user = preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]#i','',$_GET['u']); 
    ?>
```

I will like to know why ajax is not getting the name from link.

Comment: Check the console as `data: "u=":usr,` is a syntax error. Use either `data: "u=" + usr,` or `data: { u: usr },`

Comment: Still nothing. But got an error in my browser console saying `ReferenceError: usr is not defined` @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: That means `usr` isn't defined, or isn't in scope of where you're attempting to use it. Could you edit the question to include that code.

Comment: I just added the php code included in my html code. That's all of my code @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 1):

There is multiple mistakes in your code

first  you should used `data: {u: usr},` instead of  `data: "u=":usr,`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({    
        type: "GET",
        url: "fetch.php",             
        data: {u: usr},   
        success: function(d) {                    
             $("#detail").html(d); 
        }
    });
});
```

second in `fetch.php` file you should get parameter `$_GET['u']` instead of `$_GET['usr']`

```
<?php  
    // connect to db
    include 'db.php';

    if (isset($_GET['u'])) {
        $user_query = "SELECT details FROM users_det WHERE name = ?";
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_var, $user_query)) {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_GET['u']); //also change `usr` in this line
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $details);
            while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
                // fetch results
            }

            // close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }

        // echo user details
        echo $details;
    }
?>
```

for debugging you can used `console.log(d)` in ajax success response

Comment: I got the error form console log `TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement.`

Comment: remove `$("#detail").html(d); ` this line and write `console.log(d);` and check the output in console log

Answer (score 0):

First get the full url with **window.location.href**, instantiate a url object, then get its params through **searchParams** in javascript.

SCRIPT:

```
var urlString = window.location.href; //www.example.com/profile.php?u=aaron
var url = new URL(urlString);
var usr = url.searchParams.get("u");

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({    
        type: "GET",
        url: "fetch.php",             
        data: "u="+usr,   
        success: function(d) {                    
             $("#detail").html(d); 
        }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php  
    // connect to db
    include 'db.php';

    if (isset($_GET['u'])) {
        $user_query = "SELECT details FROM users_det WHERE name = ?";
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_var, $user_query)) {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_GET['u']);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $details);
            while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
                // fetch results
            }

            // close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }

        // echo user details
        echo $details;
    }
?>
```

Comment: My ajax code still doesn't get the `u=`. It has provided an error in my php code because the php code was unable to `$_GET['usr'];`.

Comment: In your php it should be $_GET['u'];

Comment: Yea, I now have no error in my console log but ajax doesn't get `u`

Comment: console.log(d) first. Did you define $details in your php code correctly?

Comment: put `var_dump($_GET['u']);` on the top of fetch.php and verify if you're indeed getting the value. If you're getting the value, that means your $details doesn't contain any data at all.